# Scheme / Racket insert-everywhere function with sublists

Tags: functional-programming, scheme, racket

So I've been trying to solve this problem:

Given an element E and a list L insert E into every position in the list L (so the result is a list of lists). Example:
`(insert-everywhere 'a '(b c))` would give `((a b c) (b a c) (b c a))`

This is easy enough but there is one other condition in my problem that is making it difficult for me - if an element of L is a list itself then the element must also be inserted into every position in the sublist. For example:

`(insert-everywhere 'd '(a (b c)))` would return: `((d a (b c)) (a d (b c)) (a (d b c)) (a (b d c)) (a (b c d)) (a (b c) d))`.

This is the code I have so far (which I mostly lifted from [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/11805/insert-everywhere-function)):

```
#lang racket
(define (insert-at pos elmt lst) 
 (if (empty? lst) (list elmt)
 (if (list? (car lst)) (insert-everywhere elmt (car lst))
 (if (= 1 pos)
  (cons elmt lst)
  (cons (first lst) 
        (insert-at (- pos 1) elmt (rest lst)))))))

(define (insert-everywhere sym lst)
  (remove-duplicates
    (map (lambda (i)
      (insert-at i sym lst))
        (range 1 (+ 2 (length lst))))))
```

where this line: `(if (list? (car lst)) (insert-everywhere elmt (car lst))` is supposed to handle the sublists but it isn't working. (If I run `(insert-everywhere 'd '(a (b c)))` with the above code I get `((d a (b c)) (a (d b c) (b d c) (b c d)))`)

If anyone has suggestions on how to approach this differently I'd be happy to hear.

Comment: So if you have a list `(b c)` `insert-everywhere` will produce a list with 3 lists in it. Using `insert-everywhere` is not correct for a sub list unless you want `(x (b c))` to become `(x ((a b c) (b a c) (b c a)))` as one of the results.

Comment: https://www.ideone.com/au9Nu1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't do indexing as it is very inefficient. Rather reverse the input list and build the list from end to beginning making the results in reverse order. You have a current list that you add elements to with `cons` that you use to add new additions to the results and each level each result that existed gets the one element added too.

As parameters you have state. When i made a reference I used `result` and `cur` and typically my iteration did like this for `(insert-everywhere 'd '(a b c))`:

```
lst     cur     results
(c b a) ()      ((d))
(b a)   (c)     ((d c) (c d))
(a)     (b c)   ((d b c) (b d c) (b c d))
()      (a b c) ((d a b c) (a d b c) (a b d c) (a b c d)))
```

Now adding support for sublists are just doing the same with them and then do a map such that you create one result per sublist in the result, adding `cur` in addition to adding it as an element.

Notice all new results are just cur with an added inserted element and all th erest gets a new element in fron which is the first element of the input. `cur` will grow and it is shared so only the elements up to the inserted element will be unique to that sub result.

I have a working implementation, but it's no fun getting the solution prematurely. Have fun.

Comment: Can you share a bit more? Are you using a helper function or is everything contained in the insert-everywhere function? I'm just having a bit of trouble visualizing the structure (haven't worked much with racket before). If I had the function definitions I'm pretty sure I could get the rest

Comment: @LainIwakura I had a named `let` that took the 3 bindings above. In a way that is a helper, but the purpose is to get the bindings to have state between calls.